# Clear way to handle singular and plural case of Models and Symbols in Rails modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For example I want to add my own has_many_stuff in ActiveRecords. So I make something like

```
module Stuff
  def has_many_stuff name
     has_many name
     stuff_model = name.to_class #What I shoud do here?
     ...
  end
end
```

The problem is there are can be different cases and singular or plural forms in the name. But rails somehow works with it. So how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://apidock.com/rails/String. There's a lot functions which might help you solve your problem. For instance, `String#pluralize` and `String#pluralize` might help with plural. After generating the string which you need you can convert it to symbol using `String#to_sym`.